# TypeError: e.persist is not a function in Typeahead Bootstrap React

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am getting the error `TypeError: e.persist is not a function` when attempting to try different methods to test my application in Enzyme but nothing seems to work.

input.prop('onChange')({target: {value: "valuehere", name: "namehere", placeholder: "placeholderhere"}});

input.simulate('change', { target: {value: "valuehere", name: "namehere", placeholder: "placeholderhere"}});

input.props().onChange( {target: {value: "valuehere", name: "namehere", placeholder: "placeholderhere"}});

My code is:

```
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';

export interface InputFormProps {
    label: string;
    id: string;
    icon: string;
    input: any;
    value: string[];
}

export default class InputForm extends React.Component<InputFormProps> {

  state = {
    value: this.props.value, list: []
   }


  async componentDidMount() {
    // API Calls happen here, not relevant
  }


  change = (value, label) => {
        //Converts to a form that the upper function understands from events
        let result = { target: {value, placeholder: label}};
        this.props.input(result);
      }

  render () {


    //Doesn't render list unless it has loaded

    return(
        <Typeahead
          multiple
          selected={this.props.value}
          name={this.props.label}
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder={this.props.label}
          id={this.props.id}
          onChange={e => this.change(e, this.props.label)}
          options={this.state.list}/>
    )

  }

}
```

Note, some values are changed to protect the privacy of my company's work.

Answer (score 1):

The library seems like it uses additional functions/properties in the event object. If you test doesn't depend on that working exactly how it does in a browser, you could stub out what's used with something like the following:

```
input.prop('onChange')({
  persist: jest.fn(),
  target: { value: "valuehere", name: "namehere", placeholder: "placeholderhere" }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@BrianMitchL's solution to mock the `persist` method is a good one, but it's important to add a little context about [React's event system](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) and why you're seeing the behavior in the first place. The events passed to handlers on React components are not native browser events:

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of `SyntheticEvent`, a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the same interface as the browser’s native event, including `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`, except the events work identically across all browsers.

For performance reasons, React [pools these events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling):

> This means that the `SyntheticEvent` object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

`react-bootstrap-typeahead` uses `event.persist()` to pass events on asynchronously after setting internal state. For example:

```
handleBlur = (event) => {
  event.persist();
  this.setState({ isFocused: false }, () => this.props.onBlur(event));
}
```

Generally speaking, if the mock event you're passing in your test is missing an attribute used in the codepath you're testing, you will get a similar error. As in @BrianMitchL's answer, you can simply mock the attribute:

```
input.prop('onChange')({
  defaultPrevented: false,
  persist: () => {},
  stopPropagation: () => {},
  target: { ... }
});
```